# Complex regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression which will do the following (working in Javascript). I want to take a string which contains some tokens like `(token)` inside parentheses. My aim is to capture the tokens (including the parentheses). I will assume that parenthese are not nested, and that every open parenthesis is eventually closed.

The regular expression I would use is

```
[[^\(\)]*|(\(.*?\))]*
```

Let me break it down:

```
[            # Either of two things:
  [^\(\)]*   # the first is a substring not containing parentheses
|
  (          # the second is to be captured...
    \(.*?\)  # and should contain anything in parentheses - lazy match
  )
]*           # Any number of these blocks can appear
```

Needless to say, this will not work (why would I be asking here otherwise?):

```
var a = /[[^\(\)]*|(\(.*?\))]*/;
a.exec('foo(bar)');
```

It fails both in Firefox and Node. My previous attempt was a slightly more compicated regex:

```
(?:[^\(\)]*(\(.*?\)))*[^\(\)]*
```

which can be described as follows

```
(?:              # A non-capturing group...
  [^\(\)]*       # ...containing any number of non-parentheses chars
  (\(.*?\))      # ...followed by a captured token inside parentheses.
)*               # There can be any number of such groups
[^\(\)]*         # Finally, any number of non-parentheses, as above
```

This will work on `foo(bar)`, but will fail on `foo(bar)(quux)`, catpuring only quux.

> How should I fix the above regex?

Comment: good thing you assumed non-nesting, otherwise it wouldn't be a regular problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have an arbitrary amount of capture groups in a regex. use the /g flag to accomplish this instead: `s.match(/\([^\)]+\)/g)`

Comment: I must admit I am puzzled. While your example does work, inverting it - that is using regex.exec(string) - does not. :-?

Comment: iirc `exec` does not support multiple matches with `/g`

Answer (score 2):

This works find - tested in Chrome

```
<your string here>.match(/(\(.*?\))/g)
```

It returns an array of matches:

```
str = 'Content(cap)(cap2)(cap3)'
str.match(/(\(.*?\))/g)
-> ["(cap)", "(cap2)", "(cap3)"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to capture the tokens inside the parenthesis (including the delimiters) then a simple regular expression like:

```
\([^)]*?\)
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

`var a= /\([^)]+\)/g;`